# Google redirect uri no longer saving?

Tags: redirect, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth, google-oauth

This is so strange...

I implemented Google OAuth2 on Site A (I'm using Ruby on Rails), successfully adding localhost:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback and sitea.herokuapp.com/auth/google_oauth2/callback to the redirect uri field in my Google Cloud Console.

Tried to do the same with Site B and... I can't set those darn redirect uris at all any more!

So I cheated a bit and used the Site A key and secret for Site B... and it all worked in localhost.

But when I finished in dev and tried to test in production by adding siteb.herokuapp.com/auth/google_oauth2/callback to that original Site A app...  not only did it not get added, but the localhost and sitea uri's got deleted, and now I can't add those back.

Help, please?  What might be happening, how do I test?

Thank you!

Comment: +1! This is really annoying. I have the exact same issue. Redirect uri's are just wiped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been having the same problem, I think it's an issue with Google Cloud Console.
I used the old user interface (https://code.google.com/apis/console) and it worked fine. Use this for the time being, it'll save you a lot of headache.

Comment: Thank you!!  That's awesome, solved my problem for now.

I hope Google employees really are tracking the google_oauth tag and are working to fix this.

Comment: Oh thanks! I knew there was an earlier version somewhere, but I mistook it for the App engine interface.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect URI saving issue was a bug, and it should be fixed by now. Please leave a comment if you still encounter it. Thanks for reporting.